# The answer is in your face

Tags: riddle, rhyme

> My first came before,
>   A tool for wood, not ore.
>
> My second prints ink,
>   I heard recent things.
>
> Together they sound quite fast,
>   I'll charge for the last.
>
> One is a simple example,
>   Protein is made ample.

***What am I?***

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> **Expression**

My first came before,

A tool for wood, not ore.

> Axe

My second prints ink,

I heard recent things.

> Press, as in a newspaper printing press

Together they sound quite fast,

I'll charge for the last.

> Axe + Press sounds like Express, which is a word for something fast.

One is a simple example,

Protein is made ample.

> Hen, a chicken.
>  Express + Hen = **Expression**
>  The expressions on your face relates to the title

Comment: Yes, but some of them aren't quite as how I intended.

Comment: I'll give it some more thought, and will accept suggestions from anyone who can figure out which piece(s) I misinterpreted. Thanks!

Comment: I'll charge for the last. - Ion

Comment: @Bulldogg6404 I don't get how you got "hen" from "One is a simple example, Protein is made ample."  I understand chicken is a source of protein, but so are a lot of other things!  Thanks if you can clarify.

Comment: I guess because "protein is made ample" meaning that hens lay eggs.

Answer (score 1):

It may be

> Screen

My first came before,

A tool for wood, not ore.

> They write before on a part made of wood

My second prints ink,

> the second is may be the "Dactilo" that prints ink

I don't know, I'm just trying to guess

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: nvm, the correct answer got accepted while I was writting this xD

Maybe it is...

> a tooth

My first came before,

> the first tooth when you are young

A tool for wood, not ore.

> beavers use them to bite the wood

My second prints ink,

> not sure about this one, maybe related to snakes and their poison?

I heard recent things.

> lost here

Together they sound quite fast,

> when you put ur tooth together and move them towards each other, they do an awfull sound (dunno how to say that in english :( )

I'll charge for the last.

> dentists charge you for your last dentures

One is a simple example,

> don't know

Protein is made ample.

> the most abundant protein in the tooth is collagen, wich is used a lot for other things

Answer (score 0):

@Bulldogg6404 has solved the riddle. Here are some of the clues which I intended:

My first came before,

> ex means before.

I heard recent things.

> The press is news.

I'll charge for the last.

> The rest of the word is -ion, which is a charged atom.

One is a simple example,

> $1$ is a mathematical expression.

Protein is made ample.

> Genetic expression can be used to make protein.